# internally generating resets verilog 2005

Tags: verilog

wanted to implement PWM sequence using top-level verilog 2005 module:

```
  module PWM_ENHANCER (

    input clk,
    input rst,
    input sent,

    //input
    input [7:0] BUF,                                        //BUFFER - The PWM reads from it only when 'sent' signal is received, and the current run is done.

    //output
    output reg PWM_WAIT,
    output reg PWM_OUT
    );
reg         [7:0] SAMPLE;
reg     [7:0]   counter;
reg     WORK;

always@(posedge clk or negedge rst)

begin 
    if( !rst )
    begin
      WORK <= 1'b0;                             //When receiving a reset, everything zeroes.
        counter <= 8'b0;
        PWM_WAIT <= 1'b1;
        SAMPLE <= 8'b0;
        PWM_OUT <= 1'b0;
    end
    else if (sent == 1 && WORK == 0) 
    begin               //If the pwm was OFF, and i received sign from the array, i start running PWM.
        SAMPLE <= BUF;
        WORK <= 1'b1;
        PWM_WAIT <= 1'b0;
    end
    else if(WORK == 1) 
    begin                               //The running block - sending '0' and '1' as needed.
            if ( (counter <= SAMPLE) && (SAMPLE != 0) ) 
            begin
                PWM_OUT <= 1'b1;
                counter = counter + 1'b1;
            end

            else if ( counter > SAMPLE )
            begin
                if ( counter == 8'b11111111 ) 
                begin
                    counter <= 8'b0;
                    WORK <= 1'b0;
                end

                else 
                begin
                    counter = counter + 1'b1;
                    PWM_OUT <= 1'b0;
                end
            end;
            if(counter == 200) 
            begin                       // 50 cycles before the end, PWM sends acknowledge for the array to send the next sample.
                PWM_WAIT <= 1'b1;
            end
    end     

    else 
    begin 
        ;                                                           // if NOT receiving 'sent' from the array - the PWM does nothing.
    end

end 
endmodule
```

received error when compiling:

"Internally generated reset in top design unit 'PWM_ENHANCER' is not allowed."

How can i have a reset included in the @always statement?

Comment: You need to specify the tool you were using to compile. This is not a Verilog language issue

Comment: Seems like something different. Please post the code, where you have instantiated this module.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibility (both synthesis related):

1. Your synthesizer needs additional hand-holding for the asynchronous reset

   ```
   if(!rst) begin
     WORK <= 1'b0;
     counter <= 8'b0;
     PWM_WAIT <= 1'b1;
     SAMPLE <= 8'b0;
     PWM_OUT <= 1'b0;
   end
   else begin
     // other logic in here
   end
   ```
2. Your standard cell library lacks flops with asynchronous reset/preset. FPGA's tend to have a limited number of flops with asynchronous reset/preset. Some FPGA do not have any. If this is the case the simplest thing that can be done is change the for asynchronous reset to synchronous reset by changing the top of your always block to `always@(posedge clk)` (omitting the `or negedge rst`).
   If you are on FPGA, then you may want to add an `initial` block to initialize the defaults of the registers.